# Do Americans who have the cot–caught merger pronounce 'all', 'tall', 'Paul', etc. with the same vowel quality as 'lot'?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonology, phonetics, vowels

Do American English speakers who pronounce *cot* and *caught* as [kʰɑt] pronounce *all*, *tall*, *Paul*, etc. with the same vowel quality?

If my subjective experience is anything to go by, I feel like I've heard Americans say [ɑ] (similar or identical to the vowel of *palm*, with no lip rounding) more in *cot*, *caught*, *don*, *dawn*, *stock*, *stalk*, etc., yet [ɔ~ɒ] (with rounding, similar to AmE *north* but with no R and to RP *thought*) more in *all*, *tall*, *Paul*, etc.

If this is true, it can be construed that either

- (a) the so-called *cot–caught* merger is incomplete before tautosyllabic /l/, just like with /ɹ/ (compare *thought* and *north*), i.e.

  > ɔ → ɑ / _ [-liquid]

  (If this is true, *doll* has to be pronounced differently from *all* because it has /dɒl/ in RP.)
- (b) there is a conditioned allophone of /ɑ/ that occurs before tautosyllabic /l/, i.e.

  > ɑ → ɔ / _ [+lateral]

Note that dictionaries are most likely of no help, because, in phonemic transcription, whether the vowel is transcribed as /ɑ/ or /ɔ/ is a rather arbitrary choice, unless there is a minimal pair of /ɑl/ and /ɔl/ (which there isn't AFAIK).

Am I right in my assumption, or maybe I'm mishearing the velarization of /l/ as rounding or something?

Comment: Sounds like Massachusetts to me, and yes, that sounds correct.

Comment: There is a minimal pair for /ɑl/ and /ɔl/ in the U.S.: [*collar*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=collar) and [*caller*.](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=caller) I really don't see how this helps you at all, though. They'd be pronounced the same in case (b) but not in case (a).

Comment: To clarify on my previous comment, the minimal pair isn't going to help because the dictionaries give the non-merged pronunciation.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks, that's a good example. However, _collar_ and _caller_ still differ in syllabification, and it is usually coda non-prevocalic /l/ that behaves differently from /l/ in other environments (e.g. velarization/vocalization). So as much as I wrote "tautosyllabic /l/", "coda non-prevocalic /l/" might have been more appropriate. I certainly have heard /ɑ/ more in _follow_, _dollar_, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any good summary of this, but I do recall heard accounts from specific speakers who say that they use something like [ɔ] before /l/ as a conditioned allophone of **/ɑ/**.

I would be very surprised if any speaker had a merger that applied in all environments *except* before /l/. It seems hard to prove that nobody has this, but I'm not familiar with any speaker who says they have this.

One thing that may be relevant is that even in accents that maintain a phonemic distinction between /ɑ/ and /ɔ/, British English /ɒl/ actually often corresponds to American English /ɔl/. I don't know of any good description of the exact contexts that conditioned this, but my impression is that for many non-*cot-caught*-merged American English speakers, /ɑl/ has a restricted distribution, occuring mainly or only before vowels. Judging from dictionary transcriptions, /ɔl/ is more-or-less standard (depending somewhat on the particular word) for non-*cot-caught*-merged American English speakers when "ol" is followed by a consonant or the end of a word (or in other words, in situations where the "l" is unambiguously a coda consonant). See my list of examples in [What source explains the different pronunciations of "hol" in "alcohol" and "hollow"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303766/what-source-explains-the-different-pronunciations-of-hol-in-alcohol-and-hol)

There is also a word spelled with "aul" where British English speakers all have short /ɒ/, but American English speakers may have either /ɔl/ or /ɑl/: *cauliflower.* Also, many British English speakers have /ɒl/ in words like *vault, fault, false,* spelled with "aul" or "al" followed by a voiceless consonant, but as far as I know non-*cot-caught*-merged American English speakers only have /ɔl/ in these words.

To sum up, I think your option (b) is more likely to be correct. It's true that speakers who don't distinguish *caught* and *cot* do maintain a distinction between *north* and *start,* but I don't think this is really analogous to a hypothetical merger of *caught-cot* with maintenance of a distinction between *caller* and *collar* (Peter Shor's example of a minimal pair). Rather, I would expect the pre-l context to be one of the **first** places where complete merger occurs, but it is quite likely that the merged vowel in this position will be realized as [ɔ], since even for non-merged speakers there is a tendency to use the phoneme /ɔ/ rather than /ɑ/ before /l/ in some contexts.

Comment: So you're saying, in other words, even in accents with the _cot–caught_ merger, the unrounding and lowering of the merged vowel (_father–bother_ merger) is resisted before /l/? I partly based my assumption (a) on the fact that the fronting of /ʌ/ is typically resisted before (coda non-prevocalic) /l/, thinking /l/ might have the capacity to prevent the preceding vowel from changing (which /ɹ/ seems to do & they're often grouped as liquid). But if it was the _father–bother_, not _cot–caught_, that was resisted before /l/, then that would explain well, especially if _doll_ rhymed with _all_.

Comment: @Nardog: Well, it's not universal. I have the cot-caught merger, and my perception is that "cot" and "call" have the same vowel, which sounds to me like [ɑ], not [ɔ]. Since I don't have a phoneme /ɔ/, I got my idea of what this sound is mainly from referencing my vowel in words like "core", listening to British accents, and listening to French. If I take my pronunciation of "core", try to remove the "r"/rhoticization, and add an "l", what I get sounds like my pronunciation of "coal" rather than my pronunciation of "call".

Comment: If _collar_ and _caller_ was kept distinct as [ˈkʰɑɫɚ] and [ˈkʰɔɫɚ] even in accents with the _cot–caught_ merger, then that could be explained as the difference between /ˈkɑ.lɚ/ and /ˈkɑl.ɚ/, again supporting the theory (b).

Comment: @Nardog: (continued from last comment) ...However, I have a hard time hearing the cot-caught distinction in American English accents. Sometimes I can vaguely tell that a speaker is using unmerged pronunciations, but I can't reproduce them accurately: when I try, it either comes out as merged [ɑ], or as an over-exaggerated [ɑ] [ɔ~o̞]. My impression is that for North American English speakers, the phoneme conventionally transcribed /ɔ/ is usually actually a bit lower than the /ɔ/ of a typical European language (e.g. Italian, French or German); it may be more accurate to use [ɒ] instead.

Comment: And conversely, British English "ɒ" and "ɔː" are apparently for many speakers actually closer in terms of phonetic value to /ɔ/ and /oː/ respectively. So there's a weird situation where a British English vowel conventionally transcribed as /ɒ/ could actually be pronounced with as much or more vowel height as an American English vowel conventionally transcribed as /ɔ/.

Comment: @Nardog: I don't have the *cot-caught* merger, and I don't believe I syllabify *caller* and *collar* any differently; I think the only difference is the vowel.

Comment: @sumelic Trying to reproduce /kɔl/ based on /kɔɹ/ and sounding like /kol/ makes sense. [These](http://clas.mq.edu.au/speech/phonetics/phonetics/vowelgraphs/USE_Monophthongs.html) [charts](http://clas.mq.edu.au/speech/phonetics/phonetics/vowelgraphs/USE_Diphthongs.html) tell that /ɔ(ɹ)/ and /o(w)/ are pretty close. In fact /ɔɹ/ in GenAm is analyzed as /o/ + /ɹ/ when it doesn't distinguish _north_ and _force_ ([Wells 1982](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=484eVQ7t8TMC&pg=PA484)).

Comment: @Nardog: that really depends on the speaker (or more probably, the regional dialect).

Comment: I'm sort of partially merged (I hear a difference, but I'm not sure others listening to me would hear it). My kids are pretty much fully merged, except that they still make a distinction between *ah* and *aw* (I know folks who merge those, as well). For all of us, *ball* and *bawl* are a minimal pair, with the vowel in *ball* equating to (our) vowel in *ah* and *bawl* equating to *aw*, which also more-or-less map to my *cot/caught*. Again, I don't know whether others would actually hear this distinction in our pronunciation (my daughter says she can't hear it when my son says it).

Comment: @1006a: That's really interesting. A distinction between "ball" and "bawl" seems very strange to me, and I wonder if it is a spelling-pronunciation or if the spelling is influencing the way you hear these words. As far as I know, there is no historical reason why these words should be pronounced with different vowels in modern English. I'm reminded of someone in the comments to another post who said that they thought that there was some difference in pronunciation between one or more of *oul* (as in "soul"), *owl* (as in "bowl"), *oll* (as in "roll"), and *ole* (as in "sole").

Comment: @1006a: Or actually, now that I think about it, the status of "bawl" as an almost onomatopoeic word may affect its pronunciation. Now that I'm thinking about it, I can imagine myself pronouncing it with a slightly lengthened or rounded vowel for emphasis, a bit like how I think I might pronounce the interjection "aww" with more rounding than the word "awe".

Comment: @sumelic Yes, I think the difference between *aw* and *awe* might be a similar "distance" between the two, though I don't think they're the same vowels for me. What about *mall* and *maul*? Those pretty much rhyme with *ball* and *bawl*, respectively, for me. Per the OED, British English seems to allow more variety in pronunciation of the former than the latter.

Comment: @1006a: Yes; "mall" does have more variance in pronunciation, but I always had the impression that it was somewhat exceptional in this regard for a word spelled with "all". The variant British pronunciation listed by the OED rhymes with "pal" and "gal". Some words taken at a late date from French and spelled with "ale" also show variance like "morale", "locale", "Internationale". I pronounce "mall" and "maul" identically, as /mɑl/.

Answer (score 2):

Merriam Webster Learner's Dictionary uses /ɑ/ in words like [ALL](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/all), [PAUL](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/paul)/POL, [CALLER](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/caller)/COLLAR...

Rounding of  /ɑ/ in some cot-caught merged speakers can be due to:

a) dark L-influence, but other vowels are affected too, the STRUT VOWEL for example can sound rounded (in words like culture, pulse, wolf, bull)
b) Californian/Canadian vowel shift, it is not uncommon to hear a rounded stressed vowel in words like MOM, POLITICS, DONNA, DOLPHIN, HONEST and these are all LOT-vowel-words.

Many cot-caught merged people (especially those from the Mountain West states, Vermont and Newfoundland) prefer the unrounded pronunciation of PAUL/POL, CALLER/COLLAR pairs...

/ɑ/ in ALL can be heard even in some cot-caught unmerged people from the South,
and of course in Northern Cities (as a result of the NCVS).

ALL in various accents> http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_001_all.htm

Some sound samples>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzyxZgccQSk&list=UUxWp_H6QUHf4Qx3clP_jYQg

Comment: I wonder if there's study on this. I've checked Wells (1982:473–476) and Labov et al. (2006:58–65), but they never mention an allophonic variant before dark /l/.

Comment: Your description on the STRUT vowel matches my experience as well. But /ʌ/ before /l/ is usually described as "remaining" in the cardinal [ʌ] region (as opposed to the modern realization near [ɐ]), and I've never seen /ʌ/ before /l/ being described as "rounded," though empirically true in my book.

Comment: The Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary pronunciation key merges *cot* and *caught* in ***all*** environments, so it really isn't evendence of anything.