# /fɑːl/, /fɔːl/ or /fɒl/?

Tags: pronunciation

Where in the USA do people pronounce 'fall' as /fɑːl/ as this version of CD recommends (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall)?

Nota bene: CD gives /ɑː/ for 'star', 'calm' and 'father'.
(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/star)

Comment: You need to look at a linguistic geography. Back vowels are all over the map.

Comment: That's how I've always pronounced it (I grew up in New York) and how I've always heard it on American TV and movies. What makes you think this is regional?

Comment: The difference between /fɑːl/ and /fɒl/ is very subtle, so I'm not sure which is actually what I say/hear. But since the dictionary says /fɑːl/ that's probably it. /fɔːl/ definitely sounds more British.

Comment: If you're American and you pronounce *column* and *call 'em* the same, you're probably pronouncing *call* as /kɑːl/. If not, you're probably pronouncing it /kɔːl/ or /kɒl/ (these are allophones in the U.S., so there's no semantic difference between them).

Comment: @Barmar: don't trust dictionaries completely. The [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fall) says /fɔl/. (And Americans pronounce it both ways.)

Comment: @Barmar, it is difficult for me to believe people pronounce 'star, far, father, calm, spa, bra,' with the vowel they use for "fall, call, paw, saw'.

Comment: @CălinCucuietuKə'lin I don't think I do. If that's the difference between those two IPA sounds, I guess it's hard to tell when listening to them in isolation, as I tried to do.

Comment: If you are Romanian, then your mental ears are deaf to our common /ɔ/ phoneme because [you lack that phoneme in your native tongue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_phonology). That's why you have such trouble with it.

Comment: @tchrist, I trained my ears and I can hear it now. The problem is that /ɔ/ is an umbrella sign covering many allophones. To be more precise, more sounds. First of all, it fell out of use with most lexicographers. When it was used, it was supposed to reflect the British /ɒ/. Now it often stands for the good ol' /ɔ:/, meaning that /ɔ:/ is more rounded than /ɔ/, which was never the case with the British /ɔ:/. By the way, Romanian has the British /ɔ:/ and even what you mean by /ɔ/. The last one in Transylvatnia. Tobevery short, there's no one single /ɔ/, and different people amalgamate them dif-ly

Answer (score 1):

In its pronunciations, the Cambridge dictionary does not distinguish between /ɑː/ and /ɔː/ in American English (except before /r/); for example, it says that Americans pronounce [*Don*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/don) and [*Dawn*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dawn) the same.

This is only true of *some* Americans, in particular, those with the [COT-CAUGHT merger.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot%E2%80%93caught_merger) This merger is widespread in Canada and the Western U.S., but is also present in scattered regions in the rest of the U.S.

The case of the word *fall* is more complicated, because the vowel precedes an /l/, so some people with the merger in most words may pronounce the word /fɔːl/  and some people who generally don't have the merger may pronounce the word /fɑːl/.

Also, note that the Cambridge dictionary's pronunciations don't always agree with its IPA notation. They pronounce the word [cross](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cross) as /krɔːs/, even though their IPA says /krɑːs/. This is because they don't screen the Americans pronouncing the words to see whether they have this merger.

Comment: Very 'scientific'...

Comment: Their pronunciation of Don sounds wrong to my Long Island ears, I think it should be pronounced like "Dahn" (sorry, don't know the IPA). Think of "Oh, Donald!" in "That Girl". I'm sure there are places that pronounce it like Dawn, but I don't consider it the mainstream.

Comment: This is what I suspected a long time ago. Namely that  no cot-caught mergers that use the "Dahn".  However,  this is what most foreigners think, that the Brits use a kind of /o/ and the Americans use a kind of /a/. The second difference being the American rhotacity.

Comment: I said 'suspected' because in the languages where you don't have this mhm, how to put it, well... continuum between /o/ and /a/, you feel that there is something that you don't quite get, butbin the end you have to work with what you have and it is either /o/ or /a/...

Comment: So, Barmar, if they do not pronounce it like Dahn nor like Dawn, then how do they pronounce it?

Comment: What dialects do the "dahn/star/ car/calm/psalm/bother/fall/Paul" Americans speak? This is what this question is about, basically. Because I don't think they exist.

Comment: @CălinCucuietuKə'lin: See this [blog page](http://loststates.blogspot.com/2011/04/say-don-say-dawn-now-i-know-where-you.html): *"Say Don," "Say Dawn." Now I know where you live.*

Comment: The problem with all the texts about the merger is that they write generally about it and not the exact quality of the old and new vowels.

Comment: @CălinCucuietuKə'lin: The exact quality of the new vowel varies. Since the vowels are merged, you can use either one, and people won't even notice the difference. In the DEW-DO merger, widespread in North America, the general wisdom is that the merged vowel is /duː/, but I would swear I've heard people pronouncing *do* like /djuː/. For the COT-CAUGHT merger, in Boston, the merged vowel generally sounds to me like /ɒː/, butI believe some people use /ɑː/. And in California, people generally use /ɑː/,  but I suspect that some people use /ɔː/ before a few consonants, like /l/.

Comment: See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404515/do-americans-who-have-the-cot-caught-merger-pronounce-all-tall-paul-etc).

Comment: The answer I keep getting are very imprecise. What is the use of ipa then? Thank you for the effort.